# Url routing errors in php in codeigniter

Tags: apache, codeigniter, routes, url

My login form on front page is displayed, but when it posts to other pages, the post does not happen. THe problem is that the url is like: http://sitename/users/action which is a 404 not found url. But when i hard code the path to controller, (that is, stop using base_url + "/users/action" and use base_url + "/system/application/controllers/users/action") it starts working. How can i fix this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i had the .htaccess file in the wrong folder, inside the system/application/config/ folder, instead of the root folder. after i pasted the file in the root folder, the problem was solved.

Answer (score 1):

Are you using `.htaccess` to hide `index.php`? If so, you need to take that into account with your routing. If not, you need to include it. e.g. if you're not hiding it, try:

`base_url+"/index.php/users/action"`

Comment: my .htaccess was in the wrong folder. your mentioning of it made me look for it again. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can also try your config/config.php folder  and fix your $config['base_url']...hope that helps.