# CodeIgniter routing - 404 error after moving to new server

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, codeigniter, mod-rewrite

At the moment I am trying to move a website to a new web server. The site uses CodeIgniter and on the old server, every route worked. On the new server none of them are working, even though I copied the entire website from the old server. This means there are no differences in .htaccess files, since the two servers contain the exact same website. Not even the default routes are working, just the home page (index.php). I included the code in .htaccess to remove 'index.php' from routed URLs, but that also does not work.

If I try to visit '1.1.1.1/~user/employees' it will give me a 404 error, which means that the CodeIgniter route is not working. The controller file is located at /application/controllers/employees.php, so I am not sure what causes the problem.

I am aware of the similar posts on the site here, but none of them could solve my problem. Configuration of the config/config.php is (partly) as follows:

```
$config['base_url'] = '1.1.1.1/~user';
$config['index_page'] = '';
$config['uri_protocol'] = 'AUTO';
```

I have tried to change the base_url, but it still does not work if it's empty. Changing uri_protocol to REQUEST_URI or PATH_INFO also does not work. Also, if I try 1.1.1.1/~user/index.php/employees (so put 'index.php/' in between) I still cannot reach the page. I checked some Apache settings as well, AllowOverride is set to ALL and the mod_rewrite module is installed and enabled. Is there perhaps something else concerning differences in both server's configurations that I could have missed?

EDIT:
I think I am a bit closer to finding out what the problem is. It is either something with Apache or .htaccess (but I already tried many things) or it has to do with the fact that the server URL is 1.1.1.1/~user rather than 2.2.2.2 as it was on the old server. Maybe I should change the baseurl or location of my .htaccess? This looks similar to my problem, but moving the .htaccess did not fix the problem: [Url routing errors in php in codeigniter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3239190/url-routing-errors-in-php-in-codeigniter). I might try re-installing Apache.

Comment: Was it in a different folder previously?

Comment: You should look in your .htaccess and search for the line beginning with `RewriteBase`. Make sure this points to the directory your app is running in. If you can reach the app on `http://www.example.com` it should only have a slash there: `RewriteBase /`. But if you have a subdirectory, such as `http://www.example.com/~user/`, add the subdir there: `RewriteBase /~user/`

Comment: @Ohgodwhy it was the same folder, since I copied all files from the old server to the new one.

@giorgio I tried several possibilities just now, but none of them worked. I guess `RewriteBase /` is correct after all.

Answer (score 1):

I think that you firstly should find out what happened.

- All requests to CI go through index.php, so you just echo something and exit in index.php file at the first line.
- If the page display what you echoed that means there is something wrong in CI, otherwise that's not because of CI. And you can focus on what cause the problem.

Sorry about my English.

Comment: I added an echo and exit to the start of the index file and the echo showed. What does this imply concerning CI? I did not change anything to those files and it works on the old server...

Comment: you should open file CodeIgniter.php in the folder system/core. And then find the "show_404". For each of them you should exit and echo something before show_404("{$class}/{$method}"). and watch the line that causes the error.

Comment: After know where causes it, you can echo URI and see whether there is something wrong or not. I'm sorry maybe It's caused by not CI. But I think you can find out what happened by this way.